# Addition of $2$ Events

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent, each uniformly distributed on $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$. Find $P(X + Y = k)$ for $2 \le k \le 2n$.

\begin{align}P(X + Y = k) &= \sum_{(x,y)\,:\,x+y=k} P(x, y) \\
&= \sum_{(x,y)\,:\,x+y=k} \frac{1}{n^2} \\
&= (k - 1)\frac{1}{n^2}  \\
&= \frac{k-1}{n^2} \end{align}

When $k = 2: (1, 1)$

When $k = 3: (1, 2), (2, 1)$

When $k = 4: (1, 3), (3, 1), (2, 2)$

When $k = 5: (1, 4), (4, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2)$

$$\#(x, y) = k - 1$$

**Textbook Answer:**

> $\frac{k-1}{n^2}\,\,\,$ for $\,\,\,2 \le k \le n+1$
>
> $\frac{2n-k+1}{n^2}\,\,\,$ for $\,\,\,n+2 \le k \le 2n$

Why are there $2$ intervals being considered?

Comment: When $k = n+3: (3,n),(4,n-1),\dots,(n,3)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is there 2 intervals being considered?

**Hint**: Look what happens if you go "backwards" from $k=2n$ "down":

- $k=2n$: $(n,n)$
- $k=2n-1$: $(n,n-1)$, $(n-1, n)$
- $k=2n-2$: $(n,n-2)$, $(n-1, n-1)$, $(n-2, n)$

etc. What you've got will keep growing with growing $k$, but at some point the number of ways to get the sum $k$ starts *shrinking*. Thereby the second formula.

Comment: How did the textbook know to split the interval at $n+1$ and $n+2$? $\frac{(2n)-(2)}{2} = n - 1$.

Comment: @A_for_Abacus This was done a bit artificially. The number of ways grows up to the maximum at $k=n+1$, where you have $(n,1),(n-1,2),\ldots,(1,n)$, so it is to be expected that one formula is valid for $k\le n+1$ and the other for $k\ge n+1$ and that both should match for $k=n+1$. And, not unexpectedly, if you check the "textbook formula for $k\ge n+2$", you will see that it is actually valid for $k=n+1$ as well.

Comment: How do I determine that $k = n + 1$ contains the maximum number of pairs?  You mean artificially as in the textbook used a computer to figure that out?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus, No, I meant the divide into cases "$n+1$ and less" and "$n+2$ and more" is a bit made up: the real divide is "$n+1$ and less" and "$n+1$ and more" - *those* are the two cases we care about. Anyways... I will probably need to update my answer later on, to clear your doubts how exactly those formulas are obtained...

Answer (score 3):

We have $x+y = k$ where $x,y \in \{ 1, \ldots, n\}$.

We need not always have $k-1$ pairs of $(x,y)$. In particular, if we let $x=1$, we will need to let $y=k-1$, however, this need not always be possible, as it is possible that $n<k-1$.

If $n\geq k-1$ and $k\geq $, there are $k-1$ pairs, this case has been discussed.

Now, if $k \geq n+2$, the smallest value of $x$ that can be taken would be $x=k-y=k-n$ and the largest value it can take would be $n$. Hence there are a total of $n-(k-n)+1=2n-k+1.$

Answer (score 2):

The first formula fails to find the probability after $n+1$, because:

When $n=2$, the sample space is: $(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)$, while $2\le k \le 4$ and 
$$k=2: (1,1); k=3: (1,2),(2,1); k=4: (2,2)$$
Note that when $k=4$, we are ignoring $(1,3),(3,1)$, because they are not in the sample space. So the two formulas must be applied: one until the middle, another after it.